# Unusual gradient inside highcharts splinarea

Tags: highcharts

Help please build chart like this https://prnt.sc/rhdcn2 It's not columns, we need area-spline with gradient like screenshot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use column series with linear gradient:

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: {
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y1: 0,
      y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, '#008022'],
      [1, '#ebfff0']
    ]
  },
  data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4917/

**Docs: https:**//www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

Comment: Thanx) And how to show only vertical lines with your example? http://prntscr.com/rhnv5a

Comment: Hi @stackdo, You need to set `yAxis.visible` to false and configure `xAxis` in a proper way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4920/